# Filling li with anchor when li is display:inline

Tags: html, css

After about 15/20 minuets of research and googling I have not found a solution.

I am trying to fill a list item with an anchor however the li is set to display inline code:

```
#nav{
    font-family:"chaparral-pro", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #404041;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

#nav a{
    color: #f9a13e;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%
}

#nav a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}


ul#navInner{
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 840px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

ul#navInner li{
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 11px 8px 16px 8px;
}

li.noBorderR{
    border: none !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="navInner">
    <li><a href="_#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="_#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="_#">Our People</a></li>
    <li><a href="_#">How can we help</a></li>
    <li><a href="_#">Newsroom</a></li>
    <li><a href="_#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="_#">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="_#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="noBorderR"><a href="_#">Text Size</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- end nav -->
```

Sorry for posting such a basic question on here! I cannot figure this one out!

If I set the a{} to display: block it puts the whole li on block, and inline-block does nothing.

Comment: 15 to 20 minutes... I have searched for 3 months for a solution to a problem (countless pages). Not to be too critical but I think you could, with a couple of hours more searching easily find an answer to this (or better still how about just playing around until you figure it out for yourself)

Comment: `li` is by default set to display inline. As is the `a` tag. what exactly is your problem here???

Comment: @PaulSullivan At least Josh did **some** research. Many people on here neglect to use search engines altogether. Although it does appear that Josh has neglected to actually ask a question.

Comment: @KevinBrydon - agreed at least SOME work was done but 15 minutes is barely enough to truly read more than 2/3 pages (and that means read and understand). And lol @ no question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use the padding and height/width on the  to fill up the space you need?

Answer (score 0):

How about applying height and width to the `<a>` tag and setting `line-height` in css to the height of the list item?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the padding and the height on the li, set these on the a and set it to display block. Then set the line-height to the same as the a height and the text will align in the middle vertically.

If you then want the links to appear horizontally, float the li left. I always find when styling navigation it is best to start with the innermost element and work out.